# How can we compare two .rtf files including their text properties(font,color,size)

Tags: python, vba

I am trying to automate comparsion of two .rtf files side by side. I want to get a idea how to compare text with their properties like color,font,size.
a little help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance!

As of now i am able to compare .txt file text only.

it will be able to compare text string including font,color,size
if any one of the above parameter is not matching then it is not a perfect match vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [pyth](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyth/) module for reading .rtf files.

Check this example:

```py
from pyth.plugins.rtf15.reader import Rtf15Reader
from pyth.plugins.xhtml.writer import XHTMLWriter

doc = Rtf15Reader.read(open("sample.rtf", "rb"))

print XHTMLWriter.write(doc, pretty=True).read()
```

Comment: Due to the design limitation it is out of use for my solution:                                   Ignore unsupported information in input formats (e.g. page layout)
Ignore font issues – output in a single font.
Ignore specific text sizes – support relative sizes (bigger, littler) only. Output in a single base size.